# New line when writing to a text file Java

Tags: java, file-io

i'm struggling with a Java class that i'm trying to implement. Have a look at the class below. Excuse any poor coding you spot, i've just started learning java.

```
 public void processFiles() 
    {

           output.print(name + " " + id + " ");


        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            String accNumber = input.next();
            int nextInt = input.nextInt();
            output.print(firstName);
            output.print(lastName);
            output.print(accNumber);
            output.print(nextInt);
            total = total + nextInt;
            count = count + 1;

        }
        output.print("There are " + count + " accounts which together hold" + total + " points.");
        closeLinks();
    }
}
```

When I open the file i've created the text is all on one line and I can't work out how to start a new line. I've tried inserting '\n' into the code without success. Can someone please help.

Comment: try using `output.println()`

Comment: Use `println` if you want to add line separator after data you print.

Comment: *" I've tried inserting '\n' into the code without success."* what does that mean? what did you get in the output? How do you check the result? What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all

```
output.print();
```

with

```
output.println();
```

This would result in printing each on a separate line

Answer (score 1):

try to use `output.println()` or `output.print(data+ "\n")`